# Can someone help me understand how to improve this post?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, automatic-deletion

This post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992043/how-to-detect-that-were-in-design-mode
was deleted.

I still think it is a useful question and a useful answer.

Some respondents were confused by the terminology of 'development mode', but this 'Is there any other way to detect whether you are a developer running the accdb or a user running the accde?' seems clear enough.

I've cleaned up some wordy discussion. Is there anything else I can do to improve the question before I request undelete?

Comment: Why didn't you upvote and/or accept the answer before the question got roomba-ed?

Comment: Anyway, that question looks good enough for me now.

Comment: Your question may be undeleted soon. But a word of warning, the [Meta Effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect) may result in some down votes once it is undeleted.

Comment: @rene Because it didn't work? Anyway, thanks for looking at it.

Comment: "useful answer that did not work" - that is an interesting concept... Are you looking to make that answer visible to others to troll them? Kind of hard to understand the intent...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I can see where that would sound odd without context. One answer was given, but I couldn't get it to work reliably. Later I found a more reliable solution, so wanted to answer. But the question had been deleted. I couldn't add an answer, but I could edit the question, so I stuck the answer in there so it wouldn't get lost before the question got undeleted. Hope that helps clarify.

Comment: Well, the meta effect worked.

Comment: @Unhandled Exception I'm sorry you got sucked into this and lost 3 points of reputation for trying to do a good deed and answer my question. I can understand people downvoting the question because they don't understand it, but I can't fathom why they downvoted your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The system only deleted this question and answer pair because there wasn't an upvoted answer on it. [Upvoting the answer would have saved it from the auto-deletion process](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) which we nickname "Roomba".

Beyond that, breaking out your "proposed answer" into an actual answer that could be upvoted and/or accepted would've been useful.

Comment: That's the plan. IIRC, it was deleted before I had an answer. Then I could only edit, not answer. So...

Comment: You can *always* answer a question in the same light as always being able to *ask* a question.

Comment: @makato Sorry for being dense, but I'm not following. At first, I couldn't answer because I didn't have the answer. Once I did, it had been deleted, so I couldn't add an answer. Now it is undeleted (thanks for that) but is closed and not accepting answers. Is there some means to answer that I'm missing?

Comment: Oh, I misconstrued your comment.  I was led to believe that you had an answer to your question in the interim before it was closed.  That's a miss on my part, sorry!

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you revise your question title.  There are 2 problems with *"How to Detect that We're in Design Mode"*.

1. We don't know what you mean by "Design Mode".
2. It appears what you actually want is to determine whether the user is running the ACCDB or ACCDE version of your database.

I think mentioning runtime within the question body also misled readers about the context of your question.  The [Access Runtime](https://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/developer/runtime.html) was not involved.  Suggest you eliminate that point of confusion.